# Working example to start canoo webtest from Groovy?

Tags: ant, groovy, webtest, canoo

I would like to start a simple webtest from Groovy with Canoo. The example [Canoo Example](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/groovyTesting.html) is not working. I think I am missing something with the Antbuilder class. Especially the "config" part, where a HashMap of properties is passed. I have tried different ways to pass properties but my most basic approach:

config_map = ['host':'www.google.com', 'port':'80', 'protocol':'http', 'basepath':'']

They all result in the same error message.  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[host:www.google.com, port:80, protocol:http, basepath:]]

Alternatively, I was looking at grails, but can not figure out if I can use a grails project to webtest a non-grails application. When I try to copy the classes from Grails, ant hangs itself again on the config line.

Does someone has a place where I could find a working example of a canoo-groovy webtest?

Comment: the sample code from the site looks like it has a typo in there. that might be the reason it didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at this blog post: [WebTest with Groovy, Maven and Eclipse](http://mguillem.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/webtest-with-groovy-maven-and-eclipse/)